# Setting background image for a Div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the background image for a div. But it aint seem to be loading..

```
html
<div class="cover"></div>

css
.cover
{
background-image: url(..images/Section.jpg);
background-size:cover;
height: 100%;
}
```

jsfiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/bfhzdpg5/

Comment: Try `url(../images/Section.jpg)`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a forward slash before images by the looks of it.